# True/fasle у инпута

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, такой вопрос. Есть два инпута. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы не меняя js (попросили не трогать js), а манипулируя только html менять параметр true/false?

html

```
<p><input type="radio" value="true" name="splitDates">Отдельно</p>
<p><input type="radio" value="false" name="splitDates">Вместе</p>
```

Javascript

```
var params = {
    splitDates: false
}
```

Comment: что значит _манипулируя только html менять параметр true/false?_?

Comment: динамически - нет

Comment: HTML - не язык программирования.

Comment: В `HTML` нет ни функций ни переменных, ничего. Только разметка страницы. Так что без `JS` тут никак.

Answer (score 1):

Если понимать ваше задание буквально, то есть не трогать JavaScript код, который написан на странице, а обойтись манипуляциями только HTML, то могу предложить один *обходной* способ.

1. Создаем файл нашего будущего скрипта, меняющего значение инпута, для работы на требуемой страницей **myscript.js**
2. Пишем необходимый код в созданный файл **myscript.js**, к примеру такой:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
       var ch = document.getElementsByName("splitDates");
       for(var index = 0; index < ch.length; index++){
           if(ch[index].checked){
               ch[index].checked = false;
           }else{
               ch[index].checked = true;
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   Про `getElementsByName` и `DOMContentLoaded` можно почитать тут:

   - [Document.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)
   - [HTML DOM getElementsByName() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)
   - [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
   - [Загрузка документа: DOMContentLoaded, load, beforeunload, unload](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)
3. Подключаем файл на странице, при этом немного поменяем разметку, добавив

   ```
   <script src="/myscript.js"></script>
   ```

Что получается в результате? JavaScript-код, написанный ранее - не трогали. Манипулировали на странице только HTML, добавили новый файл. Думаю мысль и приведенный пример достаточно ясны.

---

Либо, просто, взять блок кода, содержащий инпуты:

```
<p><input type="radio" value="true" name="splitDates">Отдельно</p>
<p><input type="radio" value="false" name="splitDates">Вместе</p>
```

заменить руками на следующий:

```
<p><input type="radio" value="false" name="splitDates">Отдельно</p>
<p><input type="radio" value="true" name="splitDates">Вместе</p>
```

Просто изменить значение `value` у тэга `input` на противоположное.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете не трогать имеющиеся скрипты. Просто допишите новые которые будут управлять этими значениями. На html такого сделать динамически нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Так нельзя. Вот вариант на `jQuery`. Если надо могу на чистом `JS` дописать.

```js
var params = {
    splitDates: false,
    joinDates: true
}

$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
 $("input[type=radio]").val(params.splitDates);
  });
  $(this).val(params.joinDates);
  $("#output").val($(this).parent("p").text() + " = " + $(this).val() + " ; " + $("input[type=radio]").not($(this)).parent().text() + " = " + $("input[type=radio]").not($(this)).val());
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type="radio" value="true" name="splitDates">Отдельно</p>
<p><input type="radio" value="false" name="splitDates">Вместе</p>

<input type="text" id="output" contenteditable="false" value=""/>
```